# Is there a tool to profile a mongodb puls index suggestion?

Tags: mongodb, profiling, database-performance

I found quite a bit of software to work with mongoDBs. [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/#third-party-open-source-tools) is a nice list of tools, but none seems to profile a mongodb, view the profile data  and also suggests actions e.g. to add an index.

Does anyone know such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a paid feature, [Cloud Manager Premium](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/cloud-manager) does offer index suggestions that may be suitable to your needs.

Alternatively, you could use [cursor.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) and analyse it's output to understand better your query index requirements in your implementation.

You may also find the following links helpful:

- [Optimize Query Performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/)
- [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/)
- [Analyze Query Performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/)
- [Performance Best Practices](https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/mongodb-performance-best-practices)